# Azure - Programmatically add new MySQL db instance

Tags: c#, mysql, azure, azure-sdk-.net

I am trying to programmatically add new `MySQL` db instance to azure portal.

I looked at this library: `https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-net` but i only see an example of how to create a `SQL Server` and not a `MySQL`.

```
var credentials = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory.FromFile(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_AUTH_LOCATION"));

var azure = Azure
    .Configure()
    .WithLogLevel(HttpLoggingDelegatingHandler.Level.Basic)
    .Authenticate(credentials)
    .WithDefaultSubscription();

var sqlServer = azure.SqlServers.Define(sqlServerName)
    .WithRegion(Region.USEast)
    .WithNewResourceGroup(rgName)
    .WithAdministratorLogin(AdministratorLogin)
    .WithAdministratorPassword(AdministratorPassword)
    .WithNewFirewallRule(FirewallRuleIPAddress)
    .WithNewFirewallRule(FirewallRuleStartIPAddress, FirewallRuleEndIPAddress)
    .Create();

var database = sqlServer.Databases
        .Define(DatabaseName)
        .Create();
```

Any idea if its supported to programmatically create a `MySQL` server as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the release notes and SDK code, it seems the ability to manage `MySQL` databases is still not supported (as of version 1.3).

What you could do is consume the [`REST API for managing Azure MySQL databses`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/mysql/) directly. For creation of database, please look at [`Create Or Update Database`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/mysql/databases/createorupdate) operation.

To get started with Azure REST API, you may find this link useful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/.

Comment: I have 1 more problem, I don't quite understand where do I get the clientId. I have the subscriptionId and the tenantId, but what is the clientId?

Comment: That would be the id of the application you’ll create.